# Is "ordering by hash" in Git slower than "ordering by pathname" in Mercurial?

Tags: git, performance, version-control, mercurial

I was interested to read [this slide deck](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Presentations?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=ols-mercurial.pdf) about Mercurial, and in particular the following slide:

> ## Taking advantage of the FS
>
> - Avoiding seeks is critical for performance
> - Traversal order matters!
> - **Ordering by hash means random seeking in the
>   working directory and degrades to random
>   seeking on copy**
> - Ordering by modification time degrades to
>   random seeking over time
> - Ordering by pathname is stable and gives
>   largely monotonic head movement

(emphasis mine)

What I'm taking from this is that: a version control system which stores objects in its object store using hashes, such as the SHA-1 hash, will ultimately be slower when reading files than an object store based on pathnames. This slide doesn't explicitly mention Git or claim that Git is slower for this reason, but that would be my logical conclusion.

I don't know Mercurial well at all, but from a little reading, I get the impression that hg repos use a file called a "manifest" to record the location and hash ID of files for a particular "changeset" (version/commit). And I notice [from the wiki](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Manifest) that the manifest does appear to include paths to files. Whereas Git uses a flat (ish) object store where all objects (blobs, trees and commits) are stored in the same directory, with commits pointing to tree objects, and trees pointing to blobs and other trees - all of which is used to reconstruct the state of the working directory for each version.

So according to the claim made in this slide, this "ordering by hash" should be slower on read for Git commands than the Mercurial manifest system.

The question: **is this accurate**? Is there any difference in read speed between Git and Mercurial, attributable to the structure of the object storage? Or is this essentially marketing for Mercurial?

Comment: If "head movement" refers to how mechanical hard drives work, then this text is seriously out of date. So even if its conclusions or implications are correct, that's no longer because of the reasons stated.  From the link it seems to have been published on 2006-06-24. SSDs were not common then.

Answer (score 1):

> The question: is this accurate?

Measure it and find out.  That's the only way to know, especially since file system formats and storage technologies change.  In particular, seek time is irrelevant on SSDs (they have no seek operation).  In 2005 or so, when these systems were being written, 8 GB of RAM with a terabyte of spinning media storage was a pretty large system.  Now it's normal to get a phone with 64 GB of RAM and half a terabyte of solid state storage; a "big" server computer has up to a terabyte of RAM, a dozen or so SSDs as cache front ends to the spinning media, and a set of 64 22TB spinning media drives for over a petabyte of disk storage.

Git also doesn't store files as *files*, but rather as *objects*, which may become *packed*.  Mercurial, meanwhile, stores files as *deltas*, but occasionally decides that the delta chain is too long and stores a new copy of the file.  Mercurial uses an extend-only file format internally for its changeset database, while Git will create new loose objects and new pack files whenever that seems profitable.  Git now also creates indexes for pack files, and multi-pack index files, and optional commit graph data structures and bitmaps and many other optimizations that have happened in the 2010s and 2020s, long after that slide deck.